# can't understand the sentence's structure and meaning

Tags: sentence-structure

I can't understand the below sentence:

> Indicate by check mark whether the registrant files or will file annual reports under cover Form 20-F or Form 40-F.

Issues:

1. Who indicate the whole thing?

Maybe it is formal to write such as :

Indicating by check mark whether the registrant files or will file annual reports under cover Form 20-F or Form 40-F.

Indicated by check mark whether the registrant files or will file annual reports under cover Form 20-F or Form 40-F.

To indicate by check mark whether the registrant files or will file annual reports under cover Form 20-F or Form 40-F.

2.`check mark` is a noun?   or  `Indicate by check` (subject) + `mark` (verb) + whether clasue (object) ?

Please break down it into `subject` ,`verb`,`object` ,and explain the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is an imperative sentence, so the unexpressed subject is "you."

**Indicate** (imperative verb)

**by check mark** (adverbial phrase) (check mark is a noun meaning this symbol: ✓)

**whether...** is an interrogative adverb that introduces a noun clause which serves as the object of the sentence.

As a whole, the sentence means you should check the box if the registrant has filed or will file the reports referenced in the forms listed in the sentence.

This is the same structure as any imperative sentence.

> (unexpressed "You") [subject] **Buy** [verb] **some** **bread** [object] **at the store** [adverbial phrase]!

Comment: In Britain we don't use the term "check mark". We call that symbol a "tick". But the part of the sentence I don't understand is "under cover". What does that mean? I know what the words mean, and I know about "undercover agents", and operating "under cover of darkness" etc. But I can't figure out what they want here. Do they mean "in a sealed envelope"?

Comment: @WS2 When a form or letter is used to introduce accompanying documents or details, the associated information is often said to be sent "under cover of" the form. Thus usage derives from the practice of stacking the various documents with the form or cover letter on top, so that it "covers" the other sheets. That is why such a letter is called a "cover letter".

Comment: @DavidSiegel I guessed it was something like that. But our phraseology is different. We call such a letter a "covering letter". And we would say "please find enclosed the documents in question". Some people may say "under cover of". But I am still a bit puzzled. It doesn't seem to make sense in the context quoted.

Comment: @WS2 I suspect that I would express "*will file annual reports under cover Form 20-F or Form 40-F.*" as "*will file annual reports under cover **of** Form 20-F or **of** Form 40-F.*". In any case it means that the report is introduced by and supports the form. "under cover" is an idiom, so it need not make logical sense.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I'm still struggling with its meaning. Would it mean the same thing if one replaced the "under cover" with  "together with"?

Comment: @WS2 I Yes, or one could rephrase to use "supported by" such as "*if the registrant will file form 40-A supported by an annual report.*" One might also use "accompanied by"  or "attached to" perhaps, with no significant change of meaning. But a particular institution is apt to have its own preferred wording for such a situation, which it is often well to follow unaltered.

Comment: @DavidSiegel That's interesting. I've never seen "under cover" used quite like that before.